# how to pass parameters to java files using pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I want to pass parameters from the pom.xml to the java files.

I tried to set a properties in the pom.

The java files didn't read them.

Answer (score 1):

---- Here's the 2 minute introduction to filtering resource files ----

First you need to specify that you want your resource filtered, by adding a "filtering" element, containing the "true" value.

In this example, I reconfigured the default resource directory:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.edwinbuck.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>template-value</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Template example</name>
    <description>
A simple pom file that copies a value into a propertie file.
    </description>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The MIT License</name>
            <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <project.build.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.project.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.project.outputEncoding>
        <property.to.be.copied>some-value</property.to.be.copied>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

This implies that the default resource directory exists, which (to match the example) should be at

```
${basedir}/src/main/resources
```

Inside that directory, there should be a resource (a file).  For this example, the file's contents look like

```
maven.build.number=${project.version}
customValue=${property.to.be.copied}
```

And the file is named

```
${basedir}/src/main/resources/example.properties
```

Upon a `mvn build` this will create a copy of the file into

```
${basedir}/target/classes/example.properties
```

but the contents of the file under the target directory will be

```
maven.build.number=1.0-SNAPSHOT
customValue=some-value
```

I hope this example (tested on Maven 3.5.4) will provide you with enough of a template to make better use of the documentation.

Cheers!

---- Original posts follow ----

Maven strives to have reproducible builds.  That means that if the build required input, you would have to provide exactly the same input to get a proper reproduction, each time.

Effectively this won't happen, as you might be unavailable, or might not type in the same item.  So, I would look to the src/main/resources directory and create a properties file.  Put the settings in there, and then rewrite your program to use settings from there.

When reading the properties file, there are a number of options.  Look to the technique that loads the properties file from the ClassLoader, as it is the approach that has the best maintainability, and offers the most amount of flexibility in the placement of the properties file.

In the event you want to support more than one kind of build, and all the builds can be done without human input, you might create a maven profile for each build.  That said, each profile will still be a reproducible build.

--- I see you've changed your wording, here's an update ---

Use a template, and the copy-resources target of the resources plugin.  You can leverage it to replace items in the resources as they get moved into the target directory

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the opposite, I'm trying to pass a variable from the pom file to the properties file in src / main / resources.

Comment: Look up how filtered resources work and use placeholders like ${project.aritfactId} in your properties file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean..I look filtered resources but I didn't fiend a way ther to pass variables  for the pom to my  properties file. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @yiaca I ammended my answer to give you a working example.  Hopefully you can use it to better understand the documentation.  Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks!! Do you know what is the mining of "customValue" or how to set his value?

Comment: @yiaca customValue is not a special meaning, it is what you want to add.  If you wanted to add "mother", you would replace "customValue" with "mother".  You set the value by editing the pom.xml file, modifying the property with the name between the ${ someName } pair.  Again, you can also choose what name you want someName to be by modifying the pom.xml file.  As long as the two names match, what you have set inside the <someName> ... </someName>; pair will replace the ${ someName } placeholder.

Comment: I realized .. simply for some reason my machine recognizes it as an external variable and no matter what value I put in pom I get the value 9300

Comment: @yiaca At this point, odds are the original question you asked isn't the question you need to ask now.  I'd do a second write-up, with the current details, taking care to not use words that make it seem like a duplicate question.  I'd include the relevant parts of the pom.xml and the resources file(s).  Odds are with that much information, you'll get an answer very quickly.  Good luck!